# How to use a react js npm package with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I need a Wheel styled picker ( which is available for iOS as the default Picker ) on Android and iOS. I'm using expo and hence I cannot use any native packages available out there.

Is it possible to use pure javascript package with react native?

I tried [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mobile-picker) but getting an error:

> cannot find self

while importing.

Is it really possible to use a library like this or is there anything I'm missing??

Comment: If your question has been answered, please consider marking the correct answer, if not, please add more info so that others can help you or help others in future visits to this post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, but no, you cannot use react components written for the web in react-native. Those libraries use `HTML` for their markup and `CSS` for the styling. React-Native uses none of those, so it will obviously not know how to display them.

So I guess that the only option is to search for some library written for react-native (Like the one already suggested) or build one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library: [react-native-picker](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker/tree/pure-javascript-version)

This library is a Wheel styled picker alternative for your issue.

Install it with:

```
npm install react-native-picker --save
```

And use it like this:

```
import Picker from 'react-native-picker';

<Picker
    style={{
        height: 300
    }}
    showDuration={300}
    showMask={true}
    pickerData={[1,2,3,4]}
    selectedValue={3}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

No. becuase react-native ui work different than web